# Is there an alternative to setting the 'derby.system.home' system property?

Tags: java, derby

So I'm using derby for a patient management learning project. I'm using the following code to set the system property for derby's database write location..

```
 Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "patient_management_databases");
 System.getProperties().setProperty("derby.system.home", path.toString());
 log.info(String.format("Set derby home to '%s'.", path.toString()));
```

My question is whether this is good practice on an application that is meant to be distributed and used in production? Changing the derby home location could cause problems in other applications using derby (I'm assuming all derby applications will access this property). Is there a way to set the path for this application only? It was saving to my project folder before which isn't ideal because of IDE indexing and having to ignore them when using VCS.

Comment: I believe your `setProperty` call is only going to affect this running Java process, not other separate Java processes on the same system. Unless you are running your application in a complex environment like an app server, you should be fine. However, if **all** you want to do is to control the location of the database data, you can do that much more easily using the JDBC Connection URL.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Thanks for the response. I did try and fail a few times but I managed to figure out that the database name in the JDBC url refers to the name of the database and it's position on the drive. I was able to get the behaviour I wanted with the following code:
`String.format("jdbc:derby:%s/%s;create=true", path.toString(), databaseName);`

Thanks for the helpful response.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the behaviour I wanted with the following code:

```
private final Path databaseDirectory = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "patient_management_databases");
String.format("jdbc:derby:%s/%s;create=true", databaseDirectory.toString(), databaseName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.getProperty("user.home")` is a nice way of abstracting the file-dependent nature of system paths. The use of Java's `Paths` abstraction is also another step in the right direction to decouple the application from the underlying file system. So the steps you have take so far are good, and may be sufficient for your use case.

However, there are multiple ways you can make the `derby.system.home` variable available to your application, and they all vary in terms of pragmatism and simplicity. I could not possibly describe all of them, but I would suggest also trying out a configuration file that you can load using different mechanisms - from the file system, from the classpath, or even from a remote server etc.